# Nurse scheduling Problem (Pair Distribution) in OR-Tools (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, scheduling, or-tools

It is about a nurse scheduling problem.  How can I implement nurse pairs in OR-Tools (C#)?
Namely:

1. Nurse-1 must not work with Nurse-2.
2. If nurse-1 works, then nurse-2 must also work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/dotnet/NursesSat.cs) give you some inspiration?

Comment: Yes, of course I know this source, I have already done some extensions, e.g. working time limits and others, but this topic is new to me.

Comment: Can someone help with the code example

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this more complete example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/dotnet/ShiftSchedulingSat.cs

you have two Boolean vars indicating if nurse_a or nurse_b are working.

question 1 is: nurse_a implies not(nurse_b) and nurse_b implies not(nurse_a)

question 2 is: nurse_1 implies nurse 2

Comment: Thanks for the answer Laurent. Would these variables have to be implemented in a loop?

Comment: You are free to define the variables in a loop. Consider accepting the question and upvoting it, if it helped you to achieve your goal.

Comment: @DimitriSluzki does the post above answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have more than 3 shifts-total 17. Code below partially works, but I have not managed for "Allow" branch for all shifts (morning + afternoon) only either morning shifts or afternoon shifts.
#`

```
        //// Employee Pairs
        ///
        List<ILiteral> employee_pair = null;
        List<ILiteral> employee_pair_MorningShifts = null;
        List<ILiteral> employee_pair_AfternoonShifts = null;

        foreach (var (e1, e2, allowed) in EmployeePairs)
        {
            foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
            {
                // Pair is allowed
                if (allowed)
                {
                    //foreach (var s in MorningShifts)
                    //{
                    //    employee_pair_MorningShifts = new List<ILiteral>()
                    //    {
                    //        work[e1, s.Index, d],
                    //        work[e2, s.Index, d]
                    //    };
                    //    IntVar employee_pairVar_MorningShifts = model.NewBoolVar($"employee_pairVar_MorningShifts (employee {e1}, shift {s}, day={d}");
                    //    employee_pair_MorningShifts.Add(employee_pairVar_MorningShifts);
                    //    model.AddBoolOr(employee_pair_MorningShifts);
                    //    objBoolVars.Add(employee_pairVar_MorningShifts);
                    //    objBoolCoeffs.Add(4);
                    //}

                    foreach (var s in AfternoonShifts)
                    {
                        employee_pair_AfternoonShifts = new List<ILiteral>()
                        {
                            work[e1, s.Index, d],
                            work[e2, s.Index, d]
                        };
                        IntVar employee_pairVar_AfternoonShifts = model.NewBoolVar($"employee_pairVar_AfternoonShifts (employee {e1}, shift {s}, day={d}");
                        employee_pair_AfternoonShifts.Add(employee_pairVar_AfternoonShifts);
                        model.AddBoolOr(employee_pair_AfternoonShifts);
                        objBoolVars.Add(employee_pairVar_AfternoonShifts);
                        objBoolCoeffs.Add(4);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Pair is forbidden
                    foreach (var s in shifts) 
                    {
                        employee_pair = new List<ILiteral>()
                        {
                            work[e1, s.Index, d],
                            work[e2, s.Index, d]
                        };
                        IntVar employee_pairVar = model.NewBoolVar($"employee_pair (employee {e1}, shift {s}, day={d}");
                        employee_pair.Add(employee_pairVar);
                        model.AddBoolOr(employee_pair);
                        objBoolVars.Add(employee_pairVar);
                        objBoolCoeffs.Add(4);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

`